# How to remove the php.ini maximum file upload size in live site in PHP 7+ and Wordpress 5.4+ versions?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, runtime-error

How to remove the php.ini maximum file upload size in the live hosting site in PHP 7+ and Wordpress 5.4+ versions?

I was facing a deep question as to how to increase my php.ini file maximum file upload size as my theme was not installing?

I tried again and again and now I am fed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

You need access to the php.ini file, without help of the hoster you can not change it.
The PHP setting is not the only limitation. The webserver itself (apache, nginx) has also a POST max size which cannot be changed by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this video out: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8fhJbrAe_A

Note that the interface might be a bit different from your hosting, however the idea should be pretty much the same.